# Squashing commits with BitBucket

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have only master on a test repo and I'm trying to squash 3 commits into one so that a file change and deletion appear as one commit.

So far, my attempts to squash have resulted in 3 commits, all with the same content.

I am not using a branch. How should I squash commits with BitBucket git?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do it is to use the command line.

### `git squash` (interactive rebase)

You have to verify that your branch is not locked for rewriting history and than from the command line do this:

```
# edit the desire 3 commits.
# keep in mind that if the commits were merged you will have more than 3 commits
git rebase -i HEAD~3
```

Now use the `s` to `squash` the desired commits into the previous one.

The order of the commits are reversed meaning that the first one that you see is the oldest of the X commits.

Here you can see a sample of how to `squash` your commits.

[image]